# Closed form for two binomial identities

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Can someone provide a **direct algebraic** solution to prove the following identity:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}=4^n$$

These are the links about this question:

[$1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37971/identity-for-convolution-of-central-binomial-coefficients-sum-limits-k-0n)

[$2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72367/proof-of-a-combinatorial-identity-sum-limits-i-0n-2i-choose-i2n-i-ch?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[$3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687221/proving-sum-k-0n2k-choose-k2n-2k-choose-n-k-4n?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[$4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186459/simplifying-the-sum-with-binomial-coefficients-sum-limits-k-0n-2k-choose?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[$5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624584/proof-of-the-identity-sum-k-0n-binom-2kk-binom-2n-kn-k-4n?noredirect=1&lq=1)

All of the answers use combinatorial interpretation or generating function (indeed none of the algebraic ways I've ever seen were direct and they all uses some default facts).
With **direct algebraic** solution I mean a solution which begins from the LHS and derives the RHS.

I tried Hagen and Rothe identity which states :

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{r-tk}{k}\binom{s-t \left(n-k\right)}{n-k}\frac{r}{r-tk}=\binom{r+s-tn}{n}$$

Setting $t=-2,r=1,s=0$ we get:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2k+1}{k}\binom{2 \left(n-k\right)}{n-k}\frac{1}{2k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2k+1}{k+1}\binom{2 \left(n-k\right)}{n-k}\frac{1}{2k+1}$$$$=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2 \left(n-k\right)}{n-k}\frac{1}{k+1}$$

---

The other one is:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{n}{k}\frac{\left(-1 \right)^k}{k+1+m}$$

I [determined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3572588/3-binomial-identities-that-i-could-not-find-a-closed-form-for-them/3573542#3573542) a closed form for this identity when $m=0$ , but I don't know how to start with this one.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see the links present.

Comment: Why do you expect that a purely direct algebraic solution would exist? A lot of these binomial summation identities come from combinatorial arguments or generating functions.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any real $ \alpha $ : $$ \left(\forall x\in\left]-1,1\right[\right),\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\displaystyle\binom{\alpha}{n}x^{n}}=\left(1+x\right)^{\alpha} $$
Thus, for $ x\in\left]-1,1\right[ $ : $$ \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{n}\displaystyle\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}x^{n}}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} \ \ \ \ \left(*\right) $$
Observe that : $$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ \left(-1\right)^{n}\displaystyle\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}=\displaystyle\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n!}\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(-\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}-k\right)}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2^{n}n!}\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(2k+1\right)}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{4^{n}}\displaystyle\binom{2n}{n} $$
Multiplying the expression $ \left(*\right) $ by itself gives the following : $$ \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{4^{n}}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\displaystyle\binom{2k}{k}\displaystyle\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}}\right)x^{n}}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-x}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{x^{n}} $$
Then we get the result : $$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\displaystyle\binom{2k}{k}\displaystyle\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}}=4^{n} $$

Comment: Nice derivation :)